# Element doesn't position itself under mouse

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm buiding a simple drag functionality:

```
<div class="i-plane">
  <div class='i-interact' @mousedown='handleDown' :style='position'></div>
</div>

<script>
  data: {
    field: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
    position: {
      transform: 'translate(' + this.field.x + 'px,' + this.field.y + 'px) rotate(' + this.rotate + 'deg)'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    handleMove () {
      this.field.x = e.clientX
      this.field.y = e.clientY
    }
  }
</scrip>
```

I thought `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` would put the `i-interact` under the cursor. But no, it's places way down:

[image]

What's the correct way of placing the `i-interact` element exactly under the cursor?

**EDIT:** I tried this:

```
// this.$el = <div class="i-interact">
this.field.x = e.clientX - this.$el.parentElement.offsetLeft
this.field.x = e.clientX - this.$el.parentElement.offsetTop
```

But the `i-interact` element still shows at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Can you add it to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Can I delete this question? I did a better one with a Fiddle.

Comment: @v́̎̈́̀̽̏̿̏͋ No, I just created a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign style dynamically, you have to have a string in `position` variable.

You can see following example to see this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="demo">
  <span :style="colorStyle"> {{age}}  </span>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        age: '132',
        colorStyle: 'color: red;'
      };
    }
})
```

see working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zv9pm92n/).

---

I see you are using data variable inside another data variable which is not possible, you can better use a computed property for such case, see sample code below:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        age: '132',
        color: 'red'
      };
    },
    computed: {
      colorStyle: function() {
         return 'color: ' + this.color + ';'
      }
    }
})
```

Updated fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zv9pm92n/1/).

Comment: The style is being assigned. It's just the position that's wrong.